# EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework

On an empty table in the database I get the this error on the index home controller on return View(context.Customer.ToList());

```
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �SelectListItems� is based on type �SelectListItem� that has no keys defined.
```

I have added the [key] attribute to the id (with getter and setter) in my model, edmx file is in my project with the table customer in it WITH the id as primary key, same as in my model.

what else do I have to do????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163156.aspx) it shows you how to "Adding an Entity Key When No Key Is Inferred from a Table"

1. Uncomment the EntityType element in the SSDL section of the .edmx file.
2. Define the key for the entity type by adding the appropriate Key elements to the EntityType element.
3. In the SSDL section, add an EntitySet element that specifies the table to which the added entity type maps.
4. In the CSDL section, add an EntityType element that corresponds to the added SSDL entity type.
5. In the C-S (conceptual to storage) mapping section, add an EntitySetMapping element that specifies the mapping between the added SSDL and CSDL entity types.

Above points taken from the link.