# EntityType 'Movie_Category_Map' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Please help me solve this problem. I've been sitting for 2 days already and found no idea where am I doing wrong. I've seen this articles below:

- [EntityType 'MyProfile' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306947/entitytype-myprofile-has-no-key-defined-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011145/entity-framework-code-first-entitytype-has-no-key-define
- [EntityType 'ApplicantPosition' has no key defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764609/entitytype-applicantposition-has-no-key-defined)
- [Entity Framework Code-First - Define the key for this EntityType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482670/entity-framework-code-first-define-the-key-for-this-entitytype)
- [EntityType 'SelectListItem' has no key defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691439/entitytype-selectlistitem-has-no-key-defined)

but I haven't solved my problem so I finally ask this. Below are my complete classes so you can replicate the issue.

`Movie` Entity

```
public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        this.MovieCategoryList = new List<Movie_Category>();
    }
    public string MovieID { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> YearReleased { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie_Category> MovieCategoryList { get; set; }
}

public class MovieMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Movie>
{
    public MovieMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(p => p.MovieID);

        // Property
        this.Property(p => p.MovieID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(15);

        this.Property(p => p.MovieName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(p => p.YearReleased)
            .IsOptional();

        // Table and Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Movie");
        this.Property(p => p.MovieID).HasColumnName("MovieID");
        this.Property(p => p.MovieName).HasColumnName("MovieName");
        this.Property(p => p.YearReleased).HasColumnName("YearReleased");

        // Relationships
    }
```

`Category` Entity

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.MovieCategoryList = new List<Movie_Category>();
    }
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie_Category> MovieCategoryList { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(p => p.CategoryID);

        // Property
        this.Property(p => p.CategoryID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(15);

        this.Property(p => p.CategoryName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(30);

        // Mappings
        this.ToTable("Category");
        this.Property(p => p.CategoryID).HasColumnName("CategoryID");
        this.Property(p => p.CategoryName).HasColumnName("CategoryName");

    }
}
```

and the `Movie_Category` which maps `Movie` to `Category` since it is a `Many-to-Many` relationship

```
public class Movie_Category
{
    public int MovieCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string MovieID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Movie_Category_Map : EntityTypeConfiguration<Movie_Category>
{
    public Movie_Category_Map()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(p => p.MovieCategoryID);

        // Property
        this.Property(p => p.MovieCategoryID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(p => p.CategoryID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(15);

        this.Property(p => p.MovieID)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(15);

        // Mappings
        this.ToTable("Movie_Category");
        this.Property(p => p.MovieCategoryID).HasColumnName("RecordID");
        this.Property(p => p.MovieID).HasColumnName("MovieID");
        this.Property(p => p.CategoryID).HasColumnName("CategoryID");

        // Relationship
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Category)
            .WithMany(t => t.MovieCategoryList)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID);

        this.HasRequired(t => t.Movie)
            .WithMany(t => t.MovieCategoryList)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.MovieID);

    }
}
```

`MovieShopContext` which inherits from `DbContext`

```
public class MovieShopContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Movie> MovieList { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> CategoryList { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Movie_Category_Map> MovieCategory { get; set; }

    static MovieShopContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MovieShopContext>(null);
    }

    public MovieShopContext()
        : base(@"Data Source=Newbie;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;Integrated Security=True;")
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MovieMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CategoryMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Movie_Category_Map());
    }
}
```

so in my `Data Access Layer`, i have this code: *i have removed the try-catch block*

```
using (MovieShopContext _db = new MovieShopContext())
{
    Movie _movie = new Movie();
    _movie.MovieID = "M-1212-001";
    _movie.MovieName = "Book of Riddles";
    _movie.YearReleased = 2001;

    _db.MovieList.Add(_movie);  // stops here

    _db.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Action Completed!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

when i try to run the code, it stops on line

```
_db.MovieList.Add(_movie);
```

and throws this exception message,

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType
>   'Movie_Category_Map' has no key defined. Define the key for this
>   EntityType.
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'MovieCategory' is based on type 'Movie_Category_Map' that has no keys
>   defined.

As far as I know, in the `Movie_Category_Map` configuration, i have already set a primary key,

```
this.HasKey(p => p.MovieCategoryID);
```

Can you point me where have I done wrong? or where am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DbSet<Movie_Category_Map> MovieCategory { get; set; }
```

This line is giving you trouble

this should be

```
public DbSet<Movie_Category> MovieCategory { get; set; }
```

You are adding EntityTypeConfiguration as an entity, so it is shouting for the Key ( which ofcourse doesn't exist )